# Customer Account - Not saving after backend edits

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, customer-account

Whenever we try to make an edit to a customer record (in the backend), it will not allow us to save.
The 'Please Wait...' loading image appears in the middle of the screen and stays there to no end.

When I refresh and log back in (after timeout) the changes are not there.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a javascript file that is not firing properly in the admin area of your 1.7 site.  It could be a missing file, it could be a permissions issue, or it could be due to a security update that changed the ACL (access control layer) in the Magento admin.

I'd try to use the console tools in your browser to see what errors is showing up in your browser session - this might help you pinpoint what's happening.

It also could be an extension that is overriding functionality; it could also be a core file change to the system that someone might have made to create custom functionality into the grid.

But before trying to delve into the code, I'd first start with the console tools in your browser to see if you can pinpoint any errors there.

Check to make sure that your SSL certificate is up to date, and that you aren't serving mixed content to the admin area (this might prevent some browsers from executing a save command).

If that doesn't work, using New Relic might be helpful too.

You can also try to replicate the site onto a demo environment and see if you're still having the same issue there.  If it is, it could be a server issue.

I hope this helps...

Comment: Checked the console tools and there was a Post error for eav-attributes. I went to the table and deleted the duplicate Mailchimp attributes. Fixed the problem.

Comment: Nice!  Glad you were able to find the post error!